# How to dynamically show loader on react button

Tags: html, reactjs, button

below is my code

```
 <button
          className="btn"
          id={index}
          onClick={() =>
            `Make an API call`
            )
          }
        >
          {loader && index =={"Dont know how to add button ID here to show loader"}? (
            <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin login-spin"></i>
          ) : (
            "Add To Cart"
          )}
        </button>
```

I have a bunch of buttons and i am planning to show loader if the user click on particular button,at the same time i am posting a request to backend, i have given index as id to each button but i am unable to access the button ID to show the loader symbol,
i do not know how to acces BTN id without click
PS:i am inside a function not a react component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the button `id` from the `onClick` event object.

Example:

```
const clickHandler = e => {
  const { id } = e.target;
  // id is button id
};

<button id={0} onClick={clickHandler}>Click Me</button>
```

Combine this with some loading state that correlates a currently loading button id. Use the current `loading` state button id to match the `id` for any specific button.

```
const [loadingId, setLoadingId] = useState({});

...

setLoadingId((ids) => ({
  ...ids,
  [id]: true
}));

...

<button type="button" id={0} onClick={clickHandler}>
  {loadingId[0] ? <Spinner /> : "Button Text Here"}
</button>
```

Full example:

```
const mockFetch = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 3000);
  });

function App() {
  const [loadingId, setLoadingId] = useState(null);

  const clickHandler = async (e) => {
    const { id } = e.target;
    setLoadingId(ids => ({
      ...ids,
      [id]: true
    }));
    try {
      await mockFetch();
    } catch {
      // ignore
    } finally {
      setLoadingId(ids => ({
        ...ids,
        [id]: false
      }));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" id={0} onClick={clickHandler}>
        {loadingId[0] ? "loading..." : 0}
      </button>
      <button type="button" id={1} onClick={clickHandler}>
        {loadingId[1] ? "loading..." : 1}
      </button>
      <button type="button" id={2} onClick={clickHandler}>
        {loadingId[2] ? "loading..." : 2}
      </button>
      <button type="button" id={3} onClick={clickHandler}>
        {loadingId[3] ? "loading..." : 3}
      </button>
      <button type="button" id={4} onClick={clickHandler}>
        {loadingId[4] ? "loading..." : 4}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-dynamically-show-loader-on-react-button]

Comment: Thanks man, I liked this approach, it's really good....

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the below approach to achieve this

1. Define a state to set the selected button id, something like
   `selectedButtonId`
2. On clicking the button, it should be set to the selected button id
   and then after your API call is success, it should be reset to the
   default value.
3. Then compare the index(id) of button with the state defined in
   step(1) to show the loader as applicable.

Here is a sample code which utilizes the above points - But just changes the button label instead of a loading icon

```
export default function App() {
  const [selectedBtnId, setSelectedBtnId] = useState(-1);
  const buttons = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
  const handleClick = id => setSelectedBtnId(id);
  return (
    <div>
      {buttons.map(({ id }) => (
        <button id={id} key={id} onClick={() => handleClick(id)}>
         {selectedBtnId === id ? 'Loading': 'Click Me'}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks man, appreciate that, I got the idea how to do that...

Answer (score 1):

I would better go with a separate component for a button that receives an index and does whatever it wants

```
function LoadingButton({id}) {
   const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(false);
   if (isLoading) return (<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin login-spin"></i>)
   return ( 
        <button
          className="btn"
          id={id}
          onClick={() =>
             setIsLoading(true)
             MakeApiRequest().then(result=>setIsLoading(false))
            )
          }
        >
          "Add to Cart"
        </button>
    )

}
```

This is a better option because it allows you to have multiple standalone loading buttons, you can click some of them and each will show a spinner.

Then you can use it like

`<LoadingButton id={index}/>`

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can just add it directly and judge that it meets the conditions for displaying the loading icon.

Comment: i cannot add directly, because i have 20 odd buttons

Comment: Oh oh, what is your judgment condition